# Finding the set of strings over {,} that ends with an odd number of "a"s

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

> I need to write a regular expression that identifies the set of all
> possible strings over Σ={,} that end with an odd number of "a"s.

I'm getting better with regular expressions, but still I'm not sure of this one. So far, I wrote the following expression, but I'm not sure if it is correct or not (and if not, why).

$$
(b^*|(a|b)^*)a(aa)^*
$$

well the last part makes sure that it ends with at least 1 or 1+2n "a"s, so I'm pretty sure this is correct. As for the first part, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Think about the string $aa$. The first $a$ is matched by $(a|b)^*$ and hence by $(b^*|(a|b)^*)$. The second $a$ is matched by the $a(aa)^*$. Indeed $a(aa)^*$ will match $1+2n$ characters, so the problem now is to make sure the prefix doesn't end with an $a$.

Comment: Hmm, that was quite helpful actually. So, the suffix is making sure that it ends with an odd number of "a"s, but it works only if the prefix ends with an "b" or if the prefix does not exist at all. So, if it exists, it must end with a "b". So, considering that I can have: $((a|b)^*b)^*a(aa)^*$. Is this correct? I think it is. Can it be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A =\{a, b\}$ and let $1$ be the empty word. A typical word of your language $L$ can be written as $uv$, where $v \in a(aa)^*$ and $u$ does not end with an $a$, that is, $u \in 1 + A^*b$. Altogether, you get $$L = (1 + A^*b)a(aa)^*$$

Answer (score 0):

@CurlyError: what u have done is correct.
Tho, I think (((a|b)*b)|eps)a(aa)* is better since this leads to a simpler NFA.
This form basically says either have a prefix ending in b or eps i.e. no prefix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).